# Display multiple markers on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to display multiple markers on the Google map in android. How can I achieve this?

Comment: pretty sure I saw that same question pass multiple time on sof ... did you try looking for an answer before posting ?

Comment: See this [Example Code Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659020/unable-to-see-multiple-marker-on-google-map/34171904#34171904) this may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `ItemizedOverlay`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) from one of my books that demonstrates this.

Comment: +1, i have referred this example, working fine as all the markers are being loaded on map successfully. Thanx for the example

Comment: But sir, in your example, whenever we click on particular marker, it is showing popup.xml layout based on the "y" axes position. But can you please let me know how do we display the popup exact above the marker? Please help me