# Custom tap window on Google Map

Tags: android

I was just looking at one of the **Google map** implemented in IPhone which contains labels and buttons.

[image]

How can I get this kind of window in Android containing labels, buttons and an image as well?
Kindly provide me source for the same.

Stone

Comment: labels and Buttons means what ??? do want to add these bottom tab and the title "SYNNYX" above or what ???

Comment: Consider first line as Name of place and second line as Address. There may be mre lines. Button takes us to details of that place. There should be an image of that place too in the window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have already given the answer of this question but I have also another one it same like you want in the given above image.

```
package com.pocketjourney.tutorials;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

      public class ShowMapWithTappingWindowActivity extends MapActivity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.tutorial2);
}

/**
 * Must let Google know that a route will not be displayed
 */
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
} 
}
```

---

```
package com.pocketjourney.view;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    /** Class to hold our location information */
    public class MapLocation {
    private GeoPoint point;
    private String name;

public MapLocation(String name,double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.name = name;
    point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1e6),(int)(longitude*1e6));
}

public GeoPoint getPoint() {
    return point;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

---

```
    package com.pocketjourney.view;

    import java.util.Iterator;
     import java.util.List;

     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
     import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
     import android.graphics.Canvas;
     import android.graphics.Paint;
     import android.graphics.Point;
     import android.graphics.RectF;
     import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
     import android.os.Handler;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
     import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
     import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
     import com.pocketjourney.tutorials.R;


       public class MapLocationOverlay  extends Overlay {

//  Store these as global instances so we don't keep reloading every time
      private Bitmap bubbleIcon, shadowIcon,iconForMapKit,iconForMapKitRollOver;
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
       private boolean flag = false;

       private MapLocationViewer mapLocationViewer;

   private Paint    innerPaint, borderPaint, textPaint;
       private Point arrowPointCoordinates = new Point();
   //  The currently selected Map Location...if any is selected.  This tracks whether                                an information  
//  window should be displayed & where...i.e. whether a user 'clicked' on a known map location
      private MapLocation selectedMapLocation;  
      private int [] start,end ;
        private boolean checkAnimationEnded;

/*
 * The Following method is to be called when to have dropping pin effect
 * the method is simply creating two arrays for starting and ending point of map location.
 * On draw will be called again and again till start point equals the end point
 */
private void fillYCoordinateArrayForPinDropAnimation(MapLocationViewer  mapLocationViewer)
{ 
    List<MapLocation> mList = mapLocationViewer.getMapLocations();
    int size = mList.size();
    start = new int[size];
    end = new int[size];
}

/*
 * Method for checking two arrays. Used for dropping pin effect
 */
private boolean checkTwoArrayForEquality(int [] a , int [] b)
{
  boolean result = true ;

  for(int i = 0 ; i< a.length ; i++)
  {
      if(a[i] < b[i]){ result = false; break; }
  } 
  Log.v("Coor", "Coor Resut = "+ result);
  return result;
}

public MapLocationOverlay(MapLocationViewer     mapLocationViewer) {
    this.mapLocationViewer = mapLocationViewer;

    bubbleIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.marker);
    shadowIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.shadow);
    iconForMapKit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.arrowformapkit);
    iconForMapKitRollOver = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.arrowformapkit_rollover);
    fillYCoordinateArrayForPinDropAnimation(mapLocationViewer);
}

@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p,final MapView   mapView)  {

    //  Store whether prior popup was displayed so we can call invalidate() & remove it if necessary.
    boolean isRemovePriorPopup = selectedMapLocation != null;  

    //  Next test whether a new popup should be displayed
    if(moreArrowTappedEvent(mapView,p) && isRemovePriorPopup)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this.mapLocationViewer.getContext(), "I am hit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        flag = true;
        mapView.invalidate();

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                flag = false;
                mapView.invalidate();
            }
        },200L);

    }
    else
    {

        selectedMapLocation = getHitMapLocation(mapView,p);
        if ( isRemovePriorPopup || selectedMapLocation != null) {
            mapView.invalidate();
        }       



    }   

        //  Lastly return true if we handled this onTap()
    return selectedMapLocation != null;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

    drawMapLocations(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    drawInfoWindow(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    // Uncomment the below for dropping pin effect


    if(!checkTwoArrayForEquality(start, end))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<start.length ; i++)
        {
            if(start[i] < end[i] ) start[i]+=3;
        }
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
    else
    {

        checkAnimationEnded = true;
    }   


   }

/**
 * Test whether an information balloon should be displayed or a prior balloon hidden.
 */
private boolean moreArrowTappedEvent(MapView    mapView, GeoPoint   tapPoint)
{
    boolean result = false;

    RectF hitTestRecr = new RectF();
    Point screenCoords = new Point();
    // Create a 'hit' testing Rectangle w/size and coordinates of our icon
    // Set the 'hit' testing Rectangle with the size and coordinates of our on screen icon
    hitTestRecr.set(arrowPointCoordinates.x,arrowPointCoordinates.y,arrowPointCoordinates.x+iconForMapKit.getWidth(),arrowPointCoordinates.y+iconForMapKit.getHeight());


    //  Finally test for a match between our 'hit' Rectangle and the location clicked by the user
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(tapPoint, screenCoords);
    if (hitTestRecr.contains(screenCoords.x,screenCoords.y)) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;

}



private MapLocation getHitMapLocation(MapView   mapView, GeoPoint   tapPoint) {

    //  Track which MapLocation was hit...if any
    MapLocation hitMapLocation = null;

    RectF hitTestRecr = new RectF();
    Point screenCoords = new Point();
    Iterator<MapLocation> iterator = mapLocationViewer.getMapLocations().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        MapLocation testLocation = iterator.next();

        //  Translate the MapLocation's lat/long coordinates to screen coordinates
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(testLocation.getPoint(), screenCoords);

        // Create a 'hit' testing Rectangle w/size and coordinates of our icon
        // Set the 'hit' testing Rectangle with the size and coordinates of our on screen icon
        hitTestRecr.set(-bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2,-bubbleIcon.getHeight(),bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2,0);
        hitTestRecr.offset(screenCoords.x,screenCoords.y);

        //  Finally test for a match between our 'hit' Rectangle and the location clicked by the user
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(tapPoint, screenCoords);
        if (hitTestRecr.contains(screenCoords.x,screenCoords.y)) {
            hitMapLocation = testLocation;
            break;
        }
    }

    //  Lastly clear the newMouseSelection as it has now been processed
    tapPoint = null;

    return hitMapLocation; 
}

private void drawMapLocations(Canvas canvas, MapView    mapView, boolean shadow) {

    Iterator<MapLocation> iterator = mapLocationViewer.getMapLocations().iterator();
    Point screenCoords = new Point();

    int pos = 0; // for drop pin effect 
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {    
        MapLocation location = iterator.next();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(location.getPoint(), screenCoords);
        shadow = false ; // remove this line if want shadow to be drawn also.. 

        end[pos] = screenCoords.y - bubbleIcon.getHeight();// for drop pin effect
        if (shadow) {
            //  Only offset the shadow in the y-axis as the shadow is angled so the base is at x=0; 
            canvas.drawBitmap(shadowIcon, screenCoords.x, screenCoords.y - shadowIcon.getHeight(),null);
        } 
        else {
            if(checkAnimationEnded)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bubbleIcon, screenCoords.x - bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2, screenCoords.y - bubbleIcon.getHeight(),null);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bubbleIcon, screenCoords.x - bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2, start[pos],null); // for drop pin effect
            }   


            //canvas.drawBitmap(bubbleIcon, screenCoords.x - bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2, screenCoords.y - bubbleIcon.getHeight(),null);
        }

        pos++;// for drop pin effect
    }
}

private void drawInfoWindow(Canvas canvas, MapView  mapView, boolean shadow) {

    if ( selectedMapLocation != null) {
        if ( shadow) {
            //  Skip painting a shadow in this tutorial
        } else {
            //  First determine the screen coordinates of the selected MapLocation
            Point selDestinationOffset = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(selectedMapLocation.getPoint(), selDestinationOffset);

            //  Setup the info window with the right size & location
            int INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH = 200;
            int INFO_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 50;
            RectF infoWindowRect = new RectF(0,0,INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH,INFO_WINDOW_HEIGHT);             
            int infoWindowOffsetX = selDestinationOffset.x-INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH/2;
            int infoWindowOffsetY = selDestinationOffset.y-INFO_WINDOW_HEIGHT-bubbleIcon.getHeight();
            infoWindowRect.offset(infoWindowOffsetX,infoWindowOffsetY);

            //  Draw inner info window
            canvas.drawRoundRect(infoWindowRect, 5, 5, getInnerPaint());

            //  Draw border for info window
            canvas.drawRoundRect(infoWindowRect, 5, 5, getBorderPaint());

            //  Draw the MapLocation's name
            int TEXT_OFFSET_X = 10;
            int TEXT_OFFSET_Y = 15;
            String name = selectedMapLocation.getName();
            if(name.length() >= 28)
            {
                name = name.substring(0, 26)+"..";
            }   
            canvas.drawText(name,infoWindowOffsetX+TEXT_OFFSET_X,infoWindowOffsetY+TEXT_OFFSET_Y,getTextPaint());
        //  canvas.drawText(selectedMapLocation.getPrice(),infoWindowOffsetX+TEXT_OFFSET_X,infoWindowOffsetY+TEXT_OFFSET_Y+20,getTextPaint());
            if(!flag)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(iconForMapKit, infoWindowOffsetX+160,infoWindowOffsetY+10, null); 
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(iconForMapKitRollOver, infoWindowOffsetX+160,infoWindowOffsetY+10, null);
            }   

            arrowPointCoordinates.x = infoWindowOffsetX+160;
            arrowPointCoordinates.y = infoWindowOffsetY+10;
        }
    }
}

public Paint getInnerPaint() {
    if ( innerPaint == null) {
        innerPaint = new Paint();
        innerPaint.setARGB(225, 75, 75, 75); //gray
        innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }
    return innerPaint;
}

public Paint getBorderPaint() {
    if ( borderPaint == null) {
        borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }
    return borderPaint;
}

public Paint getTextPaint() {
    if ( textPaint == null) {
        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }
    return textPaint;
}
}
```

---

```
package com.pocketjourney.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MapLocationViewer extends LinearLayout {

private MapLocationOverlay overlay;

//  Known latitude/longitude coordinates that we'll be using.
private List<MapLocation> mapLocations;

private MapView mapView;

public MapLocationViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MapLocationViewer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {        

    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    mapView = new MapView(getContext(),"0UHW90ofRVhQWOEMziC6Vn73Fogg9NtCmHCIGGw");
    mapView.setEnabled(true);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    addView(mapView);

    overlay = new MapLocationOverlay(this);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);

    mapView.getController().setZoom(14);
    mapView.getController().setCenter(getMapLocations().get(0).getPoint());
}

public List<MapLocation> getMapLocations() {
    if (mapLocations == null) {
        mapLocations = new ArrayList<MapLocation>();
        mapLocations.add(new MapLocation("North Beach",37.799800872802734,-122.40699768066406));
        mapLocations.add(new MapLocation("China Town",37.792598724365234,-122.40599822998047));
        mapLocations.add(new MapLocation("Fisherman's Wharf",37.80910110473633,-122.41600036621094));
        mapLocations.add(new MapLocation("Financial District",37.79410171508789,-122.4010009765625));
    }
    return mapLocations;
}

public MapView getMapView() {
    return mapView;
}
}
```

---

[image: I have got the fallowing given blow output using the above code same like you want]

I hope you got your answer.

Comment: Great. What if we want to display an image in the window?

Comment: Please read my answer care fully >> is a bitmap public class MapLocationOverlay  extends Overlay {

 //  Store these as global instances so we don't keep reloading every time
    private Bitmap bubbleIcon, shadowIcon,iconForMapKit,iconForMapKitRollOver;  iconForMapKitRollOver = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.arrowformapkit_rollover);
read it i have use bitmap and set the value of it.

Comment: Fine. How can we set a click event for the button you have displayed. Can you show how can I add click event in your code?

Comment: No i am use onTap in the place of onClick when a user click on arrow(>>) then a toast appear using this code if(moreArrowTappedEvent(mapView,p) && isRemovePriorPopup)
  {
   Toast.makeText(this.mapLocationViewer.getContext(), "I am hit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   flag = true;
   mapView.invalidate();

   mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     flag = false;
     mapView.invalidate();
    }
   },200L);
   
  }

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please check below link may be helpful to you.

[How to display popup on tapping overlay in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486864/how-to-display-popup-on-tapping-overlay-in-android)

also check

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/google-map-example-in-android-with-info.html

[Display multiple markers on Google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994800/displaying-multiple-markers-on-google-map)

Comment: @@Stone please check link may be more helpful https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme and code is directly is here https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons