# How to create a custom dialog for a itemized overlay item?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

So at the moment when i click an itemized overlay item , i just display a simple dialog, i would like to create something more in the lines of the below

[image: On tap dialog]

How would i go about doing this for the android phone>?

Comment: I posted the same question yesterday...Not much of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385908/custom-tap-window-on-google-map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override ItemizedOverlay there is protected onTap method. It has item index as parameter. You should override onTap and use this index to get correct data object. E.g:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    getItem(index); \\your overlay item
    return true;
}
```

Then you should create custom dialog from code or inflate xml layout, use correct layout params to add it on your MapView:

```
MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point, 0, 0, MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;            
    MV.addView(popup, params);
```

MV - your MapView instance;
point - your Overlay item GeoPoint;
popup - your custom dialog view.

Comment: Im called the lower piece of code in the OnFocusChanged method, but im wondering how to create the popup programitcally

Comment: actually, when should i call the lower code in the above..... As i cant call it on in my itemized overlay,

Comment: @molleman I make this with callback interface. You may write public method in your itemized overlay and call it setOnTapListener(or whatever you like) and pass your interface as parameter. Then you can call it's method in onTap. Implementation of this interface should be in your MapActivity, where you can get MapView and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a method to do that:
Extend OverlayItem and override getMarker to return a new drawable.

```
package this.is.funny;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MyOverlayItem extends OverlayItem{
    private String title;
    private Context ctx;
    private NinePatchDrawable npd;
    private Rect textBox;
    private Paint p;

```
public MyOverlayItem(Context ctx,GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet) {
    super(point, title, snippet);
    this.title=title;
    this.ctx=ctx;
    p=new Paint();

}


@Override
public Drawable getMarker(int stateBitset) {
    return new MyDrawable();
}
/**
 * 
 * I believe this method is the cleaniest way to do what we want. Not sure about it
 * @author emmanuel
 * This private class is a custom drawable with some text inside.
 */
private class MyDrawable extends Drawable{

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas c) {            

        textBox = new Rect();
                    //this is ugly
        p.setFakeBoldText(true);
        p.setTextSize(16);
        p.setAlpha(50);
        p.getTextBounds(title, 0, title.length(), textBox);
        //p.setAlpha(255);
        NinePatchDrawable npd;
        npd=(NinePatchDrawable)
```

ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.geoloc);

`npd.setBounds(-(textBox.width()/2+15),-(textBox.height()+30),textBox.width()/2+15,0);
        npd.draw(c);

        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setAlpha(255);
        c.drawText(title,-textBox.width()/2,-30,p);


    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}`

}