# Show a toast on clicking an overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I have used the following code for displaying the overlay

```
p = new GeoPoint((int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

            controller = mapview.getController();
            controller.setZoom(12);

            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(map.this, p);
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

            controller.animateTo(p, new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    controller.setZoom(12);
                }
            });
            mapview.invalidate();
```

and the file where the overlay is drawn is the following...

```
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    Point screenPts = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.overlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 32, null);
```

Could anyone please tell me what changes need to be done to display a toast when i click on an overlay??

Answer (score 0):

Override the overlay's `onTap` method ([here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html#onTap%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView%29)) and call the Toast.

Comment: onTap method works for the whole mapview.I want that the toast should be displayed only on a particular overlay and not the whole map.

Comment: The `Toast` is displayed on top of the Activity: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you want to do, but if you override the Overlay's `onTap` method any tap on the overlay will bring up the Toast. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Ah. You want to use ItemizedOverlay (see http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html) and then override the `onTap(int index)` method (see http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#onTap(int)).

Answer (score 0):

Here i am given a link of my previous given answer you should read answer with the comment then you find you answer.

```
 if(moreArrowTappedEvent(mapView,p) && isRemovePriorPopup) { 
Toast.makeText(this.mapLocationViewer.getContext(), "I am hit",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 flag = true; mapView.invalidate();
 mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override public    void    run() {
```

// TODO Auto- generated method stub
    flag = false;   mapView.invalidate(); } },200L);
    }

[Custom tap window on Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385908/custom-tap-window-on-google-map/6516706#6516706)

I have done it do you want.

I hope this is help.