# Android - Multiple markers in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im working on an android project using java, which contains a mapping feature. My problem is how to add multiple markers(two different markers) with different colors(red, blue).

I have used the google maps api. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: which google api are you using v1 or v2 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994800/displaying-multiple-markers-on-google-map

Answer (score 1):

Try out this way:

> ```
> private static final LatLng BRISBANE = new LatLng(-27.47093, 153.0235);
> private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
> private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
> private static final LatLng ADELAIDE = new LatLng(-34.92873, 138.59995);
> private static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.952854, 115.857342);
>
>
> private void addMarkersToMap() {
>     // Uses a colored icon.
>     mBrisbane = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>             .position(BRISBANE)
>             .title("Brisbane")
>             .snippet("Population: 2,074,200")
>             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
>     // Uses a custom icon.
>     mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>             .position(SYDNEY)
>             .title("Sydney")
>             .snippet("Population: 4,627,300")
>             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
>     // Creates a draggable marker. Long press to drag.
>     mMelbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>             .position(MELBOURNE)
>             .title("Melbourne")
>             .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
>             .draggable(true));
>     // A few more markers for good measure.
>     mPerth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>             .position(PERTH)
>             .title("Perth")
>             .snippet("Population: 1,738,800"));
>     mAdelaide = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>             .position(ADELAIDE)
>             .title("Adelaide")
>             .snippet("Population: 1,213,000"));
>     // Creates a marker rainbow demonstrating how to create default marker icons of different
>     // hues (colors).
>     int numMarkersInRainbow = 12;
>     for (int i = 0; i < numMarkersInRainbow; i++) {
>         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>                 .position(new LatLng(
>                         -30 + 10 * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / (numMarkersInRainbow - 1)),
>                         135 - 10 * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / (numMarkersInRainbow - 1))))
>                 .title("Marker " + i)
>                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(i * 360 / numMarkersInRainbow)));
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Grishu, this is exactly what I wanted. But now I have saved the latitudes and longitudes in database. Is it possible to retrieve the latitudes and longitudes from database and display directly on the map?

Comment: Yes you can retrieve the lat long from the database by querying and display directly on map. You need to put the effort for that dear :) Please vote the answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks :)